# MySQL multiple joins with Many-To-Many relations

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have three tables that matter to me: customer, client_assignment and customer_products. The last two are assignment tables for Many-To-Many-relations.

In client_assignment a customer of the type `client` gets associated with another customer (where `customer_id` is the parent and `client_id` the child).
In customer_product I associate customers with products.

A client can not be associated with a product, he inherits it from his parent-customer. In the example below this means, that *Foo-1* also has product 3, because his father (*Foo*) has it.

```
customer (Customers):
+-------------+-------+----------+
| customer_id | name  | type     |
+-------------+-------+----------+
|           1 | Foo   | customer |
|           2 | Foo-1 | client   |
|           3 | Foo-2 | client   |
|           4 | Bar   | customer |
|           5 | Foob  | customer |
+-------------+-------+----------+

client_assignment (Customer/Client-Assignment):
+-------------+-----------+
| customer_id | client_id |
+-------------+-----------+
|           1 |         2 |
|           1 |         3 |
+-------------+-----------+

customer_product (Customer/Product-Assignment):
+-------------+------------+
| customer_id | product_id |
+-------------+------------+
|           1 |          3 |
|           1 |          4 |
|           1 |          5 |
|           4 |          3 |
|           5 |          7 |
+-------------+------------+
```

I want to accomplish the following: Select all customers **and** their respective clients that are associated with product X.

My desired result for product 3 is something like this:

```
+-------------+-------+--------+
| customer_id | name  | parent |
+-------------+-------+--------+
|           1 | Foo   | null   |
|           2 | Foo-1 | 1      |
|           3 | Foo-2 | 1      |
|           4 | Bar   | null   |
+-------------+-------+--------+
```

I've been thinking about this for a bit and it seems fairly complicated. I've tried joining them like the following:

```
SELECT c2.customer_id, c2.name, c1.customer_id as parent
  FROM  customer_product p, customer c1, customer c2, client_assignment a
 WHERE 
           c1.customer_id = p.customer_id 
       AND c2.customer_id = a.client_id 
       AND a.customer_id = c1.customer_id 
       AND p.product_id = 3
```

I know, that this query will not give me the exactly desired result, but I've created it to start with. The main problem about it is, that it does only select the clients, and not the customers themselves. Therefore I only get *Foo-1* and *Foo-2* as a result, but not *Bar* or *Foo*.

The question is: Is this reasonably easily achievable, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write another `SELECT` that gets the customers themselves, and combine the two with `UNION`:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.name, NULL AS parent
  FROM customer AS c
  JOIN customer_product AS p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
 WHERE c.type = 'customer' 
  AND p.product_id = 3

UNION

SELECT c2.customer_id, c2.name, c1.customer_id AS parent
 FROM customer_product AS p
 JOIN customer AS c1 ON c1.customer_id = p.customer_id
 JOIN client_assignment AS a ON a.customer_id = c1.customer_id
 JOIN customer AS c2 ON c2.customer_id = a.client_id
WHERE c2.type = 'client'
  AND p.product_id = 3
```

Comment: I've not even thought about using a `UNION`. This works exactly like I wanted, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to get names of both clients and parents of the client, a way of doing it is by using `UNION`.

```
with customer_names as (select customer_id from s_customer_product where product_id =3),

client_names as (select client_id , customer_id as Parent_id from s_client_assignment join customer_names using(customer_id))

select customer_id , name , null as Parent from  s_customers join customer_names using(customer_id) 

union 

select a.client_id , b.name , a.parent_id as Parent from client_names a, s_customers b where b.customer_id = a.client_id;
```